# sheaf of germs of horizontal endomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

In the following [paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1970__39__175_0/), I see the notion of sheaf of germs of **horizontal endomorphisms of $\mathcal E$** where $\mathcal E$ is a vector bundle on a scheme $S$.
Any thoughts on what is the definition of this sheaf?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the same paper in case it is useful to someone in the future:

Let $(\mathscr  E,\nabla)$ and $(\mathscr  F, \nabla')$ be quasi-coherent $\mathscr O_S$-modules with T-connections.
An $\mathscr O_S$-linear mapping $\phi : \mathscr E\to \mathscr F$ is called horizontal if $\phi(\nabla(D)(e))=\nabla'(D)(\phi(e))$ whenever $D$ and $e$ are sections of $\operatorname{Der}(S/T)$ and $\mathscr E$ respectively over an open subset of $S$. In other words, whenever the commutator $[\phi, \nabla(D)] = 0$.

Taking $\mathscr E=\mathscr F$ we get a horizontal endomorphism of the T-bundle $(\mathscr E, \nabla)$.

Comment: Please use \to (or the appropriate \rightarrow, \leftarrow, etc) for arrows and \operatorname for operators that are not already defined in MathJax: these make your post easier to read. I have updated your post with these formatting changes.

Comment: Thank you very much @KReiser